what was the first instance or context of mentioning the word Islam in dawah of prophet mohamad
what was the first instance or context of mentioning the word Islam in "dawah" of prophet Mohamad PBUH ? Please provide the context or first instance from Quarn or prophet's saying and the reaction of the listeners to the prophet.
Thanks in advance
